# How to extract the comma separated string values per row?

Tags: string, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34a2H.png)
[image]

Purpose: To find out each Test Case ID associated per test script ID.
e.g. TSI_001 has three test case IDs i.e. 665, 666, 667 etc

Till now I could get the test case IDs but I am not able to make the association with test script ID..

Can anyone please help?

Comment: And do what with them? ie. put them in separate cells? find if it exists in the string?

Comment: Sorry to mention that I wanted these things to be handled using Selenium Java.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Office Support article](https://support.office.com/en-za/Article/split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)

If you need to code it, have a look at [this page](http://www.excelfunctions.net/split-string-in-excel.html) which goes through some of the functions which you may find helpful.